# How to use ViewPager with min sdk 13

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to include a fragment with a viewPager for a little app with:

- sdk min 13, target 19
- all activities extending android.app.Activity
- all fragments extending android.app.Fragment

Trouble is I'm not able to access the v4 support library ?

Answer (score 1):

Put `android-support-v13.jar` in `libs/`. This contains all of the classes from `android-support-v4.jar`, plus versions of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that work with `android.app.Fragment`.

If your app already has `android-support-v4.jar` in `libs/`, you can get rid of it when you add in `android-support-v13.jar`.

Comment: If the project is Gradle-based, it's preferable to include library dependencies via their Maven coordinates instead of copying jars into the libs folder. The build system can disambiguate multiple copies of the libraries if multiple dependencies link to them.

Comment: @ScottBarta: Very true. I am used to answering questions with Eclipse/Ant solutions. I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio, I solved the problem by including the following line in build.gradle:

```
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+"
```